# memoir's adjustwidth environment mis-adjusts the right margin?

Tags: margins, memoir, adjustwidth

Here is my simplest file where I see this problem:

```
\documentclass[article,titlepage,12pt,openany,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\shademar}
\setlength{\shademar}{2.5\FrameSep}

\newenvironment*{ShadeAux}[2]%
{\begin{adjustwidth}{\shademar + #1}{\shademar + #2}\begin{qshade}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{qshade}\end{adjustwidth}\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{ShadeAux}{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\lipsum[12]
\end{ShadeAux}
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[12]
\end{quotation}
\begin{ShadeAux}{\leftmargin}{\leftmargin}
\lipsum[12]
\end{ShadeAux}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The first length `\shademar` is there to remove the protrusion of the `qshade` environment into the margins.  As you can see, the first call to `ShadeAux` works as expected.  But the second call to `ShadeAux` indents inward the right margin more than it should.

As a response to the comments: the reason I did not initially add `\shademar` before the àdjustwidth` environment is that I am trying to be clever and not have two define two (or one) extra length: i.e. one for the left margin, one for the right margin.

Why is it going wrong?

Comment: Why not save yourself the trouble and do `\setlength{\shademar}{\dimexpr 2.5\FrameSep + \leftmargin\relax}` and then simply `\begin{adjustwidth}{\shademar}{\shademar}`?

Comment: @jon In fact `\leftmargin` is meant to take the place of an adjustable margin (which is to say, a variable length accessed by #1, for instance).  In reality ShadeAux is a function with two arguments.  But since I am supposed to submit a minimal example, I abstracted away the functional part, and give an example which shows that the error happens even outside the context of a function.

Comment: @jon what is the function of `\dimexpr`?

Comment: `\dimexpr` evaluates an expression for `dimen` (requires e-TeX). But I still don't understand what you're trying to do or what `\leftmargin` is doing in the calculation anyway: if you remove it from both sides and simply use `\begin{adjustwidth}{\shademar}{\shademar}`, with or without my `\setlength` suggestion above, you get the same result.

Comment: the two instances of `\leftmargin` have different values as adjustwidth sets `\leftmargin` based on the first argument, and then you use it again in the second.  You should do the arithmetic before calling the environment as jon said.

Comment: please fix your example document so that it produces the problem described. As posted it can not be run at all, if I add `\documentclass{memoir}` it just produces an error `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.19 \begin{ShadeAux}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry.  i forgot to add the two initial lines to the displayed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adjustwidth` sets `\leftmargin` so when it comes to look at the second argument the input value has already changed, if you evaluate both lengths first you get a different result (hopefully the one you intended)

[image]

```
\documentclass[article,titlepage,12pt,openany,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}
\newlength\zzza
\newlength\zzzb
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\shademar}
\setlength{\shademar}{2.5\FrameSep}

\newenvironment*{ShadeAux}[2]%
{%
\setlength\zzza{\shademar+#1}%
\setlength\zzzb{\shademar+#2}%
\begin{adjustwidth}{\zzza}{\zzzb}\begin{qshade}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{qshade}\end{adjustwidth}\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{ShadeAux}{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\lipsum[12]
\end{ShadeAux}
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[12]
\end{quotation}
\begin{ShadeAux}{\leftmargin}{\leftmargin}
\lipsum[12]
\end{ShadeAux}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I noticed a small error in your code.  You should have `\setlength\zzzb{\shademar+#2}` instead of the line you have with the `#1`.  Otherwise it works.  I had not considered that `adjustwidth` would change the value of `leftmargin` between the left-margin use and the right-margin use.